# Changing SQL "Where" clause based on form input

Tags: php, mysql, forms, checkbox, dynamic

Trying to figure out a simpler method besides this huge section of code to dynamically create this SQL statement

On the form I have checkboxes engine1 - engine6 of which someone could select all or none of (selecting none currently = effectively the same as selecting all which is how I want it)

the below code works and generates the SQL statement correctly just wondering if there is a better way to do it?

First section of code determines what the first checkbox is and the second set of code adds the remaining ones based on check status and includes the needed "OR" to the statement.

```
   $SQLselect  = "SELECT * FROM enginedataview ";
    if (!empty($_POST["engine1"])){
        $SQLselect = $SQLselect ."WHERE engine_id = 1";
        $starteng=1;
    }
    elseif (!empty($_POST["engine2"])){
        $SQLselect = $SQLselect ."WHERE engine_id = 2";
        $starteng=2;
    }   
    elseif (!empty($_POST["engine3"])){
        $SQLselect = $SQLselect ."WHERE engine_id = 3";
        $starteng=3;

    }   
    elseif (!empty($_POST["engine4"])){
        $SQLselect = $SQLselect ."WHERE engine_id = 4";
        $starteng=4;

    }
    elseif (!empty($_POST["engine5"])){
        $SQLselect = $SQLselect ."WHERE engine_id = 5";
        $starteng=5;

    }       
    elseif (!empty($_POST["engine6"])){
        $SQLselect = $SQLselect ."WHERE engine_id = 6";
        $starteng=6;

    }       
    switch($starteng){
        case "1":       
            if (!empty($_POST["engine2"])){$SQLselect = $SQLselect ." OR engine_id = 2";}
            if (!empty($_POST["engine3"])){$SQLselect = $SQLselect ." OR engine_id = 3";}
            if (!empty($_POST["engine4"])){$SQLselect = $SQLselect ." OR engine_id = 4";}
            if (!empty($_POST["engine5"])){$SQLselect = $SQLselect ." OR engine_id = 5";}
            if (!empty($_POST["engine6"])){$SQLselect = $SQLselect ." OR engine_id = 6";}
            break;
        case "2":
            if (!empty($_POST["engine3"])){$SQLselect = $SQLselect ." OR engine_id = 3";}
            if (!empty($_POST["engine4"])){$SQLselect = $SQLselect ." OR engine_id = 4";}
            if (!empty($_POST["engine5"])){$SQLselect = $SQLselect ." OR engine_id = 5";}
            if (!empty($_POST["engine6"])){$SQLselect = $SQLselect ." OR engine_id = 6";}   
            break;
        case "3":
            if (!empty($_POST["engine4"])){$SQLselect = $SQLselect ." OR engine_id = 4";}
            if (!empty($_POST["engine5"])){$SQLselect = $SQLselect ." OR engine_id = 5";}
            if (!empty($_POST["engine6"])){$SQLselect = $SQLselect ." OR engine_id = 6";}   
            break;
        case "4":
            if (!empty($_POST["engine5"])){$SQLselect = $SQLselect ." OR engine_id = 5";}
            if (!empty($_POST["engine6"])){$SQLselect = $SQLselect ." OR engine_id = 6";}
            break;
        Case "5":
            if (!empty($_POST["engine6"])){$SQLselect = $SQLselect ." OR engine_id = 6";}   
            break;
    }
```

Comment: There sure is, see [**PDO prepared statements**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: will look that up tomorrow and check the others answers I have gotten and reply.    I figured there had to be a simpler way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks those that answered.  I was able to look up the prepared statements and modify your suggestions a bit to get something working it probably isn't the best code as I haven't been doing this in several years and trying to re-learn everything.  Still have to go through and make everything pretty, but I have the data coming up as I want it.  The prepared statements are nice, there are probably lot other things out there like that I don't know exist that would make my life easier.  Posting my as current working code in case someone else finds this and it would help them.

Database connection $conn then this

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM enginedataview WHERE engine_id = ?");
```

Form - POST
create loop for 1-6 engines and get data from DB for each

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $i = 1;
    while ($i <7) { 
        if (!empty($_POST["engine". $i])){
        $engineid = ($_POST["engine". $i]);
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $engineid);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        if ($result->num_rows > 0){
?>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">ENGINE # <?php echo $i ?></td>
        </tr>
```

some more just HTML setting up header columns 
then loop going through data from each engine to display data

```
<?php
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            echo "<tr><td align='center'>". $row["date"];
            echo "</td><td align='center'>". $row["time"];
            echo "</td><td align='center'>". $row["oilpressure"];
            echo "</td><td align='center'>". $row["coolanttemp"];
            echo "</td><td align='center'>". $row["volts"];
            echo "</td><td align='center'>". $row["fuelpressure"];
            echo "</td><td align='center'>". $row["rexhausttemp"];
            echo "</td><td align='center'>". $row["lexhausttemp"];
            echo "</td><td align='center'>". $row["rinletairpress"];
            echo "</td><td align='center'>". $row["linletairpress"];
            echo "</td><td align='center'>". $row["fuelfilterdiff"];
            echo "</td><td align='center'>". $row["oilfilterdiff"];
            echo "</td><td align='center'>". $row["loadpercent"];
            echo "</td><td align='center'>". $row["aftcooltemp"];
            echo "</td></tr>";  
        }
            echo "</tbody></table></td></tr>";


        }

    }
        $i++;       


}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this ?

```
<?php
$ids = array();
for ($i = 1 ; $i < 7 ; $i++) {

  if ($_POST['engine' . $i] == $i) {
    $ids[] = $i;
  }
}

$SQLselect  = "SELECT * FROM enginedataview WHERE engine_id IN(" . implode(', ', $ids) . ")";
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest something like this, but haven't tested by myself:

```
for($i = 1; $i <= maxEngines; $i++) {
if(isset($_POST['engine'.$i])){
    $ids[] = $_POST['engine'.$i]
    $marks[] = "?";
}
}


$query = "SELECT * FROM einginedataview WHERE engine_id IN ("
foreach($marks as $mark) {
 $query .= implode("," $marks);
}
$sql = $dph->prepare($query);
$i = 1;
forach($ids as $id) {
 $sql->addParam($i, $whereValue);
 $i++;
}
```